# How do I display the post_title with get_permalink?

Tags: posts, title

I want to display the post title instead of the link to it with get_permalink.

`get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID)` only shows the link to the post!

Comment: You cannot get post title with that function. Why can't you use something like `<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>` ??

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! I was able to solve it with:

```
<a href='".get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID)."'>".get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID)."</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, you can use

```
<?php the_title() ?>
```

[`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Or anywhere else, try

```
<?php echo get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) ?>
```

[`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)